# why my stepper does't give the correct value when I tap the increment button?

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I am using kw stepper pod, since it is customizable. I can separate the increment button, decrement button and using my own label. but the behaviour should be the same as UIStepper

[image]

that is what it looks like, it consists of 1 increment button, 1 decrement button and counter label.

here is the code on my view controller:

```
import UIKit
import KWStepper

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var decrementButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var incrementButton: UIButton!

    var stepper: KWStepper!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stepper = KWStepper(decrementButton: decrementButton, incrementButton: incrementButton)
        stepper.autoRepeat = false
        stepper.autoRepeatInterval = 1
        stepper.wraps = false
        stepper.minimumValue = 0
        stepper.maximumValue = 100
        stepper.incrementStepValue = 1
        stepper.decrementStepValue = 1
        stepper.value = 0.0

        counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"


    }

    @IBAction func incrementButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"

    }


    @IBAction func decrementButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"

    }
}
```

I connect the increment and decrement button using @IBAction touch up inside event.

so I expect when I tap the increment button, it will increase from
 0,0 -> 1.0 -> 2.0 -> 3.0 and so on.

but in my case, when tap the increment button it will give
0,0 -> 0,0 -> 1,0 -> 2,0

the 0,0 will appear twice. why it appears twice ? how to solve this issue

I know that I can see the stepper value from value change event like this

```
stepper
    .valueChanged { stepper in
        // ...
    }
```

but I need to separate the event from increment and decrement button

here is the project on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IgeVW1OemRttoAOqJ6Ba8LpyZC_rc3-o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this a separate issue from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148257/why-my-stepper-value-inside-collection-view-cell-doesnt-change)?

Comment: yes, it is totally different :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `incrementButtonDidTapped` and `decrementButtonDidTapped` methods are possibly being called before `stepper.value` changes, since `KWStepper` also listens for `touchUpInside` events from both of these buttons to change its value.

`KWStepper` exposes two properties `decrementCallback` and `incrementCallback` which you can use to get notified when the value gets decremented/incremented. You can use these instead of an `IBAction` on the two buttons.

```
stepper.decrementCallback = { (stepper) in
    self.counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"
}

stepper.incrementCallback = { (stepper) in
    self.counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"
}
```

Alternatively, you can confirm to `KWStepperDelegate` and implement `KWStepperDidIncrement` and `KWStepperDidDecrement` delegate methods to get notified.

```
import UIKit
import KWStepper

class ViewController: UIViewController, KWStepperDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var decrementButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var incrementButton: UIButton!

    var stepper: KWStepper!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stepper = KWStepper(decrementButton: decrementButton, incrementButton: incrementButton)
        stepper.autoRepeat = false
        stepper.autoRepeatInterval = 1
        stepper.wraps = false
        stepper.minimumValue = 0
        stepper.maximumValue = 100
        stepper.incrementStepValue = 1
        stepper.decrementStepValue = 1
        stepper.value = 0.0

        // Set the delegate
        stepper.delegate = self

        counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"


    }

    @objc func KWStepperDidIncrement() {
        counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"
    }


    @objc func KWStepperDidDecrement() {
        counterLabel.text = "\(stepper.value)"
    }
}
```

Comment: the first approach using stepper.decrementCallback is the correct answer, but it doesn't work when I try using KWStepper delegate. thanks :)

Comment: @Alexa289 it should have worked. Did you set the `stepper.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your click events with following code

```
@IBAction func incrementButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    stepper.valueChanged { (steper) in
        self.counterLabel.text = "\(steper.value)"
    }

}


@IBAction func decrementButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    stepper.valueChanged { (steper) in
        self.counterLabel.text = "\(steper.value)"
    }

}
```

Comment: So an explanation of the problem is that the label was being changed after the button was tapped, but BEFORE the value was changed?